# I get key error whenever I try to encode categorical_features in my dataframe

Tags: categorical-data, one-hot-encoding, keyerror

These are the names of categorical features names that I have stored in a list

```
my_list=['MSZoning','Street','LotShape','LandContour','Utilities','LotConfig','LandSlope',
'Neighborhood','Condition1','Condition2','BldgType','HouseStyle','RoofStyle','RoofMatl',
'Exterior1st','Exterior2nd','MasVnrType','ExterQual','ExterCond','Foundation','BsmtFinType2',
'Heating','HeatingQC','CentralAir','KitchenQual','Functional','GarageType','GarageFinish',
'GarageQual','GarageCond','PavedDrive','SaleType','SaleCondition']
```

my code for encoding is as follows:

```
for cols in my_list:
    df[cols]=pd.get_dummies(df[cols],drop_first=True)
```

I get the following error:

```
KeyError: 'MSZoning'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
```

I tried the above method for another dataset but it worked just fine but here it is giving me above error.

Comment: Please add the whole error you are getting. You have omitted a part of the error message.

Answer (score 0):

First of all , welcome to the Stack Overflow

```
for cols in my_list:
    df[cols]=pd.get_dummies(df[cols], drop_first=True)
```

**Reason of getting error**:

You are getting KeyError because of the attribute **drop_first=True** in pd.get_dummies() function.

**Explanation**

So before making any dummy column pd.get_dummies() function is checking whether that column is present in the dataframe or not.

For example, you want to make dummy column **MSZoning** in the your dataframe **df**. So the function (get_dummies) is first checking whether **MSZoning** column is present in your df or not. If it is present in the df, it will delete that column and make a new column with the name **MSZoning** because you have written **drop_first=True** which means the drop or delete the first column of the same name whose dummy is to be created right now.

**Solution**

Remove that line **drop_first = True** and write it like below

```
    for cols in my_list:
        df[cols]=pd.get_dummies(df[cols])
```

Comment: Hello thanks for your help but this technique drop_first worked when using it for loan predictions categorical features so why cant we drop_first "MS_ZOning" while we want its dummies only and not the categorical column itself could you elaborate the difference between using drop_first and not using it??

Comment: Well i would recommend you to check the spelling of your columns ARE THEY CORRECT ? . Secondly I already explained it in my answer that drop_first removes the first occurrence of the column with the same name e.g. if your dataframe has columns 'a', 'b', and 'c'. And suppose you want to make dummy of 'a' again. so drop_first will remove the 'a' column previously present in the dataframe and make a new dummy column with the same name 'a'.